# Losing page number on form post laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have two dropdowns one for asc desc and one with the field name. When I change page I am able to keep the order and order_by parameter and the page number. When I change one of the dropdown a postback happens In that case I lose the page number. How can I fix this problem.

Here is the url I want

```
home?orderby=created_at&order=desc&page=2
```

Here is the url I have in the case of a dropdown change

```
home?orderby=created_at&order=desc
```

Here is my front end code

```
<form action="{{ route('home') }}" method="GET">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label for="nom">Trier par :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-tier form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="orderby" id="orderby" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="nom" {{ Request()->orderby == 'nom' ? ' selected' : '' }}>Nom</option>
            <option value="created_at" {{ Request()->orderby == 'created_at' ? ' selected' : '' }}>Date de création</option>
            <option value="updated_at" {{ Request()->orderby == 'updated_at' ? ' selected' : '' }}>Date de modification</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-tier form-group ">
        <select class="form-control"  name="order" id="order" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="desc" {{ Request()->order == 'desc' ? ' selected' : '' }}>Desc</option>
            <option value="asc" {{ Request()->order == 'asc' ? ' selected' : '' }}>Asc</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="pagination" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
     {{ $grilles->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}
</div>
```

Here is the code of the controlleur

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $sort = "ASC";
    if($request->get('order')==="desc")
    {
        $sort="DESC";
    }
    

    if ($request->get('orderby')==="created_at") {
        $grilles = Grille::orderBy('created_at', $sort)->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query());
    } else if ($request->get('orderby')==="updated_at") {
        $grilles =Grille::orderBy('updated_at', $sort)->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query());
    }
    else{
        $grilles =Grille::orderBy('nom', $sort)->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query());     
    }

    return view('home', compact('grilles'));  
}

<div id="pagination" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
     {{ $grilles->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? : $grilles->appends(request()->except('page'))->withQueryString()->links()

Comment: @user2916349 Yes, I did but it does not work. But thank you for your help